# Pick random numbers until number is high enough [javascript]

Tags: javascript, if-statement, random, while-loop

I am building a Pathfinder Character Generator, but struggling to get the stats rolls high enough. So I'd like to tell it to reroll unless the total modifier is higher than 10.

Dice are rolled 4 times, and the three highest rolls are added to make a single stat. Six stats are served into an array to work from. The total modifier is calculated by adding all six stats together, subtract 60 and divide that number by 2. So I've got all that shown here.

I assume I'm looking for an if/else statment now where if checkModifier() < 10 then run rollStat() again else move forward. But I'm not sure what that would look like. Or would it be better to simplify the whole thing into a single function and then run it as a while statement?

EDIT: There was an issue with the code producing the same six stat numbers. I've fixed it.

```
function makeDie(sides) {
    var die = function () {
        return 1 + Math.random() * sides | 0;
 };

die.times = function (count) {
    var rolls = [];
    for(var i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
        rolls.push(this());
    }
    return rolls;
 };

 return die;
}

var rollStat = function () {
    var dieRolls = makeDie(5).times(4)
    for (a in dieRolls) {
        dieRolls[a] += 1;
    }
var sortedRolls = dieRolls.sort();
    var singleStat = 0;
        for (b = 1; b < sortedRolls.length; b++) {
            singleStat += sortedRolls[b];
        }
    return singleStat;
}

var sixStats = function () {
    var ss = [];
        for (var c = 0; c < 6; c++) {
            ss.push(rollStat());
        }
    return ss;
}

var stats = sixStats();
var stats = stats.sort(function (a, b) { 
    return a - b;
});

var checkModifier = function() {
    var total = 0;
        for (var d in stats) {
            total += stats[d];
}
return (total-60)/2;
};
```

Comment: Haven´t looked at all the code but stats is an array of always the same values, is that the intended behaviour? Also, in rollStat function you have a loop under var dieRolls = makeDie(5).times(4); which is doing nothing, why is that?

Comment: if you are generating "random" numbers where the min acceptable number is ten, then just add ten.

Comment: @juvian it is adding 1 to each random number so that I get a number between 2 and 6. And now that I type that out, I'm realizing there's probably a better way to do that. As to the array: I had simplified the code and just realized I removed the functionality to get 6 different random numbers.

Comment: I've edited my solution below to adjust for your changes - let me know if it's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/auxqfscp/4/) with the solution I'd give after seeing your edit.

```js
var createStats = function () {
    var stats = sixStats();

    stats = stats.sort(function (a, b) { 
        return a - b;
    });

    var total = 0;
        for (var d in stats) {
            total += stats[d];
        }
    var totalModifier = (total-60)/2;
    if (totalModifier < 10) {
        return createStats();
    } else {
        return totalModifier; //of course, ultimately you will probably want to return stats, not the totalModifier, but this is here for debugging purposes.
    }

};
```

You can see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/auxqfscp/2/) as a proof of concept.

Another, perhaps neater solution:

```js
var genStats = function () {
    var stats = sixStats();

    stats = stats.sort(function (a, b) { 
        return a - b;
    });

    return stats;
};

var totalMod = function (stats) {
    var total = 0;
        for (var d in stats) {
            total += stats[d];
        }
    var totalModifier = (total-60)/2;
    return totalModifier;
};

var createStats = function (minMod) {
    var stats = genStats();
    if (totalMod(stats) < minMod) {
        return createStats(minMod);
    } else {
        return stats;
    }

};
```